# Copying recursively files in Python

Tags: python

I was looking to copy a whole directory and its files but also printing each file name that its being copied.

I was using a simply call to `cp -rf dir dest` with `os.system` but I cant print each filename separately as obvious.

I then thought about listing eash directory file by calling recursively ls with `os.system`, saving the whole string, split them on an array, and implement a for loop to run os.system("cp " file1 + " des/") and printing the filename, but it looks like lot of work.

Any better ideas to accomplish this?

Comment: Add the `-v` switch to `cp` and it will display every file it copies.

Comment: You can use `os.walk` and `shutil.copy`.

Comment: Using the -v verbose option would not be enough as I need to process a bit the filenames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to get the entire directory listing and use that listing to copy all files iteratively. Something like

```
file_paths = [os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk('.') for f in files]
for path in file_paths:
    print path
    shutil.copy(path, target)
```

Alternatively according to `MatthewFranglen`'s comment you can just do `shutil.copytree(src, dst)`. That will also allow you to ignore things but you'll need to define a function to do that instead of using an if in the list comprehension.

```
# ignore all .DS_Store and *.txt files
file_paths = [os.path.join(root, f) for root, _, files in os.walk('.') for f in files if (f != '.DS_Store') or f.endswith('.txt'))]
```

compared to

```
from shutil import copytree, ignore_patterns
ignore_func = ignore_patterns('.DS_Store', '*.txt')  # ignore .DS_Store and *.txt files
copytree('/path/to/dir/', '/other/dir', ignore=ignore_func)
```

Comment: The os.walk command returns directories (root), contained directories (dirs or d), and contained files (files or f). When you join the contained directory to the contained file you create a path which is unlikely to work and certainly is not what you intended.

Comment: @MatthewFranglen very true, edited script to only join together root and filename(s).

Comment: @MattiLyra Great! I would just comment that shutil.copytree can do it all in one command. I still like knowing the longer version though!

Comment: @MatthewFranglen that is also very true, I included that in the answer as well. Thanks for the comments.